# Powershell - Allow user to exit or continue script

Tags: powershell, loops, counter

I'm a beginner at powershell script. I've written the following script but can't seem to get it to work. When the script is run, after every minute it should output the number of minutes elapsed into a notepad. This should continue non-stop until the user intervenes. If the user presses the "s" key then the script will pause and they'll be asked if they want to continue the script or exit the script. If they type "y" the script will continue from where it left off, else it will stop and exit.

Below is my code:

```
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$i=1

do
{
    $key = if ($host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable) {
        $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown')
        }

    if ($key.Character -eq 's') {
            write-host -nonewline "Continue? (Y/N) "
            $response = read-host
            if ( $response -ne "Y" ) {exit}
        }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    $myshell.sendkeys("$i.")
    $i++

} while ($true)
```

This doesn't seem to do anything at all. Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not a powershell-guy, but didn't you miss the `while` part?

Comment: @AlexanderSantos oops! edited

Comment: Needs parentheses while (some condition)

Comment: Side-tip, you can also use `while($true)` as while will always be running, no need for `$j`

Comment: @AlexanderSantos thanks, that's much neater, updated

Comment: @DougMaurer updated. The issue now is that when I get the prompt `Continue? (Y/N)` irrespective of whether I type `Y` or `N` it just exits the script

Comment: Please update the question (or create a new one) with the current issue.

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using? I pasted your code into v7.0 and the Continue statement worked fine. Actually, it was the whole "press "s" to pause thing that didn't work for me.